# Finding a list of target machines to run Fuchsia on

Tags: fuchsia

Has anyone found a current list of machines that one could target Fuchsia to, as of today?  (I did a generic full build of Fuchsia on my Linux laptop, as an experiment.)  But, now I'd like to go the next step and try to deploy it on some hardware and take a look.

I'm thinking along the lines of a laptop (chromebook) or maybe a
tablet.

I've found only Google's 'fuchsia.dev' website and it's
documentation.  But I can't find a forum that is discussing Fuchsia to any extent. [ The paltry 25-30 postings here don't indicate much enthusiam. ] Anyone know of such a forum?  Without such a forum and some
specific experiences, I'm coming to believe that Fuchsia isn't quite ready for much of any experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

In the [fuchsia.dev website](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/hardware/pixelbook), there's a place that talks about how to install fuchsia on a device, with instructions for the Google Pixelbook and intel NUCs. There's also experimental hardware (like the Khadas VIM2).

Recently, the added several [mailing lists](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/contribute/community/get-involved#join_a_mailing_list) to interact with the community. There's also the #fuchsia irc channel in FreeNode where some of the devs hang out.

Comment: Thanks for that, Marco.